# How to maintain autocomplete value in for loop vue js

Tags: vue.js

I want to add dynamic row in the table with one column as autocomplete and other two as text box. The state of the other two column is being maintained and also values can be fetched. But for the autocomplete dropdown on click of add new row it disappear from all the autocomplete.

on click of add new the value selected on dynamic generated column value disappears. It would be great if I can add one autocomplete at top and on selection of item and generate dynamic row with editable qty and price text box.

```
<template>
      <v-content id="purchaseOrder-line">
        <v-card raised>
          <v-card-actions>
            <h2>Purchase Order List</h2>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-row
              ><v-autocomplete
                v-model="select"
                :items="products"
                :loading="loading"
                :search-input.sync="search"
                color="white"
                hide-no-data
                item-text="productname"
                item-value="Id"
                label="Search Product"
                placeholder="Start typing to Search"
                return-object
                solo
              ></v-autocomplete
            ></v-row>
            <div class="my-2">
              <v-btn class="normal" :text="true" @click="addNewRow()">
                <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>Add
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn class="primary" :text="true" @click="deleteAll()">
                <v-icon>mdi-delete-empty</v-icon>Delete All
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-card-actions>
          <v-card-text>
          
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="LeadLineTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(pline, index) in purchaseOrderLine" :key="index">
                    <td>
                      <v-autocomplete
                        v-model="pline.product"
                        :items="products"
                        :loading="loading"
                        :search-input.sync="search"
                        color="white"
                        hide-no-data
                        item-text="productname"
                        item-value="Id"
                        label="Search Product"
                        placeholder="Start typing to Search"
                        return-object
                        solo
                      ></v-autocomplete>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="pline.qty"
                        solo
                        label="Qty"
                        clearable
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <v-text-field
                        v-model="pline.price"
                        solo
                        label="Price"
                        clearable
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <v-btn
                        class="mx-2 waves-effect waves-block delete-po"
                        @click="deleteRow(index)"
                        :text="true"
                        small
                        fab
                        dark
                        color="teal"
                      >
                        <v-icon small>mdi-delete-empty</v-icon>
                      </v-btn>                
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr v-show="purchaseOrderLine.length == 0">
                    <td
                      colspan="5"
                      style="
                        text-align: center;
                        height: 100px;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                      "
                    >
                      No record available
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            
    
            <br />
            <button v-show="purchaseOrderLine.length" type="button" @click="save">
              Save
            </button>
          
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-content>
    </template>
    <script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue";        
    export default Vue.extend({
      name: "purchaseOrder-line",
      props: {
        msg: String,
      },       
      data() {
        return {
          output: "",
          purchaseOrderLine: [] as PurchaseOrderLine[],
          line: {} as PurchaseOrderLine,
          headers: [
            {
              text: "Product",
              align: "start",
              sortable: false,
            },
            { text: "Qty" },
            { text: "Price" },
            { text: "", value: "actions", sortable: false },
          ],
          totalRecords: 0,
          products: [] as Product[],
          result: {} as APIResponse<Product>,
          loading: true,
          search: "",
          select: null,
        };
      },
      watch: {
        search(val) {
          val && val !== this.select && this.getProductList(val);
        },            
      },        
     
      mounted() {
        this.getProductList("");
      },
      methods: {
        deleteAll() {
          this.purchaseOrderLine = [];
        },
        addNewRow() {
          this.line = {} as PurchaseOrderLine;
          this.purchaseOrderLine.push(this.line);
        },
        deleteRow(_index) {
          this.purchaseOrderLine.splice(_index, 1);
        },
        cloneRow(_index) {
          this.purchaseOrderLine.splice(
            _index + 1,
            0,
            this.purchaseOrderLine[_index]
          );
        },
        save() {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.purchaseOrderLine));
          this.output = JSON.stringify(this.purchaseOrderLine);
        },
        async getProductList(value) {
          
        },
      },
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
```

Please provide some example to do this.